# AngularFirebase not reading data from database and displaying in HTML

Tags: angular, ionic2, angularfire2

So I have a firebase DB, and I am trying to read data from it and display it on a webpage.

This is my typescript file

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-course',
  templateUrl: 'course.html'
})
export class CoursePage {
  courses: AngularFireList<any[]>;
  public Course= {};
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
    let id = navParams.get('id');
    this.courses = this.afDB.list('/courses');
  }

}
```

and this is my html

```
  <ion-header>
        <ion-navbar>
          <ion-title>
            Select Your Course!
          </ion-title>
        </ion-navbar>
      </ion-header>

      <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                    <ion-item class="text" *ngFor="let course of courses$ | async">
                        {{course.title}}
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
```

This code makes sense because the variable 'courses' is the courses collection from the database, and in my HTML, I am displaying the title of each course from courses (the db). But, I am just met with a white screen, no errors, just nothing happening. Can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: open up console and see which errors are coming ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `valueChanges()` or `snapshotChanges()` on `this.afDB.list('/courses')`.

Check the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md) for more information:

> **valueChanges()**
>
> **What is it?** - Returns an Observable of data as a
>   synchronized array of JSON objects. All Snapshot metadata is stripped
>   and just the method provides only the data.
>
> **Why would you use it?** - When you just need a list of data. No snapshot
>   metadata is attached to the resulting array which makes it simple to
>   render to a view.
>
> **When would you not use it?** - When you need a more complex data
>   structure than an array or you need the key of each snapshot for data
>   manipulation methods. This method assumes you either are saving the
>   key for the snapshot data or using a "readonly" approach.
>
> **snapshotChanges()**
>
> What is it? - Returns an Observable of data as a
>   synchronized array of AngularFireAction[].
>
> **Why would you use it?** - When you need a list of data but also want to
>   keep around metadata. Metadata provides you the underyling
>   DatabaseReference and snapshot key. Having the snapshot's key around
>   makes it easier to use data manipulation methods. This method gives
>   you more horsepower with other Angular integrations such as ngrx,
>   forms, and animations due to the type property. The type property on
>   each AngularFireAction is useful for ngrx reducers, form states, and
>   animation states.
>
> **When would you not use it?** - When you need a more complex data
>   structure than an array or if you need to process changes as they
>   occur. This array is synchronized with the remote and local changes in
>   the Firebase Database.